# Find class schedules near our location

Tags: google-search

How can we find class schedules nearby? In this case our location is New York.

Some of my friends, graduates of science major (biology, math, physics), are looking for classes that teach web development skills: HTML 5, JavaScript, CSS, server side, and database management.

The first place they went was Google. They tried all sort of search terms: "HTML 5 classes", "web development classes". etc. None gave them any link to classes nearby.

Is there a web app that can do this? Or is there a better way to look for this information through Google search?

Answer (score 1):

(As far as I'm aware), there is currently no standardised way or place to get the actual information, so there is no way of indexing and searching for them.

If you're looking for "hackdays" or something along those lines, though, there are often small communities or people in the area that know about those kinds of things.

If it was me, I'd probably start by ask around on Twitter to try and get in touch with someone who knows about those kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good one: https://tutsplus.com/

And for onsite classes in your area: http://www.webucator.com/

Comment: I think the OP is referring to real classes, not online courses.